# Error handling in Serde default field functions

Tags: rust, serde

Serde provides a way to insert a [default for a field](https://serde.rs/attr-default.html). This calls a function named the same as the default provided. For instance:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    #[serde(default = "default_name")]
    pub name: String,
}

fn default_name() -> String {
    "unnamed"
}
```

This works great. However, I'd like to use as the default the name of the directory the file is found in. This version of `default_name` looks like this:

```
fn default_name() -> Result<String, CustomError> {
    // Get the name of this directory
    let current_directory = env::current_dir()
        .map_err(|e| CustomError::new(ErrorKind::IoError, "There was an io err"))?
        .clean()
        .to_str()
        .unwrap();
    Ok(current_directory.to_string())
}
```

(I'm omitting the `CustomError` and `ErrorKind` code - you could swap in any valid such code. Or just turn it to a string.)

This won't compile, however, because `serde` is expecting a function signature that returns the type of the value (in this case a `String`), not a `Result` object. Is there a way to get `serde` to propagate the error that is surfaced here? I could do a number of things to squelch the error, such as change the field to an option or just pass back a hard-coded default value, but I have to assume there isn't a lot of point in providing a function to call for the default unless there is the possibility that function fails somehow. What is the idiomatic way to handle this?

(To be clear, in this situation I want the program to hand the error back to the code that was trying to parse the configuration file to manage cleanly. A panic isn't really an option.)

Comment: This seems like a case where you need to implement the Deserialize trait yourself and cannot rely solely on the derive macro.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I'm not entirely sure how to do that, either, and have the error handled if it arises. I'll play around with it, though!